# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}$ is continuous and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}$$

a) Prove $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$

b) Is $f$ uniformly continuous? Justify your answer.

I know that $f$ is the sum of continuous functions of $x$, and so it is continuous. How can I more rigorously prove this? Here's what I have. 
$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(nx)}{1+n^3}| \leq |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^3}| < |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}| =|\zeta(3)|$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: since $\sin(nx)'= n \cos(nx) \le n$ we see that $|\sin(n(x+\epsilon))-sin(nx)| \le n \epsilon$, yes ? hence $|f(x)-f(x+\epsilon)| \le \sum_n \frac{|\sin(n(x+\epsilon))-sin(nx)|}{n^3+1} \le \sum_n \frac{\epsilon n}{n^3 +1} \le C \epsilon$ with $C = \sum_n \frac{ n}{n^3 +1}$. the fact that all this is independent of $N$ (the $N$ appearing in  $\sum_{n=1}^N$) also proves that the series converges uniformly to $f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

The given series **converges uniformly** on $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $f$, since each term is a continuous function on $(-\infty,\infty)$ thus $f$ is a **continuous** function on $(-\infty,\infty)$. The uniform convergence of the series may be obtained from the normal convergence:
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left|\sin(nx)\right|}{1+n^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{1+n^3}<\infty. 
$$ On the other hand, from
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ny)}{1+n^3}\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left|2 \cos \left( {{nx+ny} \over 2} \right) \sin \left( {{nx-ny} \over 2} \right)\right|}{1+n^3} \leq \underbrace{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^3}\right)}_{<\infty}|x-y|, 
$$ where we have used $|\sin x|\leq |x|$, we deduce that  $f$ is **uniformly continuous** on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: The uniform convergence part is not quite right. You start with a strange statement like $|\sum_n f_n| \le \dots $ But you haven't even shown $\sum_n f_n$ has any meaning yet. It seems you are using the Weierstrass M test, but aren't saying so.

Comment: The first part of my answer tells that the series is uniformly convergent  on $\mathbb{R}$ (since it is normally convergent on $\mathbb{R}$), this gives more than a meaning to $f:=\sum_n f_n$. Then the second part of my answer proves that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|$ giving the uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm afraid I don't see your point.

Answer (score 1):

a)  Note: $|f_n(x)| = \Bigg| \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}\Bigg| \leq \Bigg|\frac{1} {1+n^3} \Bigg|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Observe also that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {1+n^3}\leq \infty$.

So by the Weierstrass M-Test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note also that $f_n = \frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^3}$ is uniformly continuous for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it follows from the **Term -by-term Continuity Theorem** (Abbott 2nd edition page 188) that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

b) A uniform limit on a set $I$ of uniformly continuous functions on $I$
is uniformly continuous on $I$.

Comment: It would be complete to mention that **each term** is a **uniformly continuous** on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your first line: You say $|f_n(x)| \le 1/(1+n^3)\le \infty.$ So by Weierstrass M test, … What you want to say is $|f_n(x)| \le 1/(1+n^3),$ and $\sum 1/(1+n^3)<\infty.$ Therefore by Weierstrass M, $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I revised the statement.